# How can I check which objects are currently tracked by the Session in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, orm, sqlalchemy

I know I can use the `Session.new`, `Session.dirty`, `Session.deleted` attributes to check objects that have been added, modified, or deleted from the `Session`.

However, after I've added an object `o` to the `Session` and committed, `o` won't show up in any of those `Session` attributes above, although `o` is still being tracked by the `Session`, i.e. subsequent modifications are reflected in `Session.dirty`.

```
s.add(o)
s.commit()
# s.new, s.dirty, s.deleted are now all empty (none contain o)
```

How can I see all objects tracked by the `Session`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Individually you can check whether a single object is in the session using `in`:

```py
if some_obj in session:
   do_something()
```

To see all tracked instances, you can inspect the `identity_map`, from [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.identity_map):

> Iterating through `Session.identity_map.values()` provides access to
>   the full set of persistent objects (i.e., those that have row
>   identity) currently in the session.

Comment: Thanks. Since a row identity is required to show up in `identity_map.values()`, this won’t show `add()`'ed, but not yet `flush()`'ed objects?

Comment: Correct, but prior to the flush those objects would still be in `Session.new` as you mentioned in your question.